# npm install unauthorized error on install for private registry

Tags: node.js, git, npm, gitlab

I am trying to install a project and I get a npm 128 error code on one dependency of the project.

```
npm install
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\git.EXE ls-remote -h -t git@gitlab.mysite.com:myprivaterepo
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Permission denied, please try again.
npm ERR! Permission denied, please try again.
npm ERR! git@gitlab.mysite.com: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-13T12_19_31_285Z-debug.log
```

I am normally using gitBash with agent running in background for ssh connections and I can directly clone from the gitLab repo of the incriminated dependency but i can't from the main project with npm install.
I also tried to execute the command that is throwing the error and it works:

```
 git ls-remote --tags --heads git@gitlab.mysite.com:myprivaterepo
0099c1913ecc392394413554c5b22f2ea0b22b43        refs/heads/feature/generate-manifests
b67ca49f1d6ec9cf77ddd233a4f7b25d7a977d75        refs/heads/master
8787a2dafbfebef21a9cf77c8081b745979e76fe        refs/heads/refactor/use-docker-compose-pull
70ee2ca3e44b6dedb4d4cf3984cec20dcf3283be        refs/tags/1.0.0
9260ee68b9fd4972f18a51dc7c21d2a8559bc51e        refs/tags/1.0.0^{}
fa44564e49035b5c1eecaeb9092332e60b5dfa0a        refs/tags/1.0.1
0c3ef1ec8621614c83668841a69769c496d74ee4        refs/tags/1.0.1^{}
86a351644be3994f0bcd8b4cdbd2b9721d296440        refs/tags/1.0.2
f5c24db1d09cc3d35aa35816b8ad5528c60b6d79        refs/tags/1.0.2^{}
cc0b8bf529390eb9c1137aeeee82925b3f37c985        refs/tags/1.0.3
3002e6cce768eff4bdb6872b7856763065e0f545        refs/tags/1.0.3^{}
37fbaa00a3ffe116113af98243bb5abffd4e7d3a        refs/tags/1.0.4
fac2008469dd9c1bb20b5a3d811586ee04527664        refs/tags/1.0.4^{}
d209098860a9f6f6b562431a065500bff2b2702f        refs/tags/1.0.5
b67ca49f1d6ec9cf77ddd233a4f7b25d7a977d75        refs/tags/1.0.5^{}
```

Tried also with yarn and I have the same problem.
Tried also different node versions from the latest to the 8.0.0 or deleting and re-installing from scratch node and npm.

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "ssh://git@gitlab.mysite.com/myproject/myfolder"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "my-keyword"
  ],
  "author": "my@email.com",
  "license": "mylicense",
  "dependencies": {
    "my-dependency": "git+ssh://git@gitlab.mysite.ch:my-repo/my-folder/my-repo",
    "lodash": "^3.10.1",
    "xml2js": "0.4.17"
  }
}
```

Someone has any hint on what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Francesco and welcome to SO!

I think the problem is that the git process executed by npm runs out of the scope of your Git Bash, which is a MinGW. It looks like npm executes `git.exe` in pure windows context, hence it doesn't know anything about your MinGW environment. I would suggest you to place your ssh-keys both in `~/.ssh` in Git Bash and in `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh` in windows. Or to create symbolic links on MinGW side.